# How do I create a lowpass feedback loop for an allpass reverberator?

Tags: python, signal-processing

I'm trying to develop an AllPass Reverberator, but I got stuck when I have to create a loop on the lowpass filter (as in the image below). I understood the three cascade allpass filters, but in the code I don't know how to create the loop. The last process is to create the last image.

[image]

[image]

The code that I created is this (and stops at the end of the three allpass):

```
def allpassfb(DataIn, sr, Mix, Spread, Diffusion = 0.7):
    delayAllPassMs = [23.8, 7.6, 2.6] 
    print('lista delay AllPass ms', delayAllPassMs) 
    # valore massimo della perturbazione in % rispetto ai delayMs(10%)
    SpreadPerc = 0.1
    # inizializzo come delay massimo l'ultimo valore della lista (+ eventuale Spread)
    delayMaxMs = delayAllPassMs[-3] * (1 + Spread * SpreadPerc)
    # inizializzo i vettori dei delay con degli 0
    pAllPass = np.zeros(len(delayAllPassMs))

    # creo la perturbazione sui delay degli allpass
    for i in range(len(delayAllPassMs)):
        pAllPass[i] = delayAllPassMs[i] * Spread * SpreadPerc
    
    # loop dell'elaborazione dei delay sugli allpass
    for i in range(len(delayAllPassMs)):
       
       # lascio invariati i delay del canale opposto ai comb
       delayAllPassL = delayAllPassMs[i]
       # calcolo i nuovi delay derivati dalla perturbazione degli allpass
       delayAllPassR = delayAllPassMs[i] + pAllPass[i]
       
       if isStereo:
           InL = DataIn[:, 0]
           InR = DataIn[:, 1]
           # inizializzo i vettori d'uscita
           Y0 = np.zeros(len(InL))
           Y1 = np.zeros(len(InR))
           # filtro il segnale con gli allpass (perturbazione sull'altro canale)
           Y0 = allpassSch2(InL, sr, delayAllPassL, Diffusion, delayMaxMs)
           Y1 = allpassSch2(InR, sr, delayAllPassR, Diffusion, delayMaxMs)
           
       else:
           In = DataIn
           Y0 = np.zeros(len(In))
           Y1 = np.zeros(len(In))
           Y0 = allpassSch2(In, sr, delayAllPassL, Diffusion, delayMaxMs)
          
           Y1 = allpassSch2(In, sr, delayAllPassR, Diffusion, delayMaxMs)
           
           
    # processo l'uscita stereo con il valore Mix (da 0 a 1)
    if isStereo:
       DataOut0 = Y0 * Mix + InL * (1.0 - Mix)
       DataOut1 = Y1 * Mix + InR * (1.0 - Mix)
       
    else: 
       DataOut0 = Y0 * Mix + In * (1.0 - Mix)
       DataOut1 = Y1 * Mix + In * (1.0 - Mix)
       
    # ricostruisco il vettore multidimensionale in uscita    
    return(np.column_stack((DataOut0, DataOut1)))
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I added a bunch of other parameters, but they don't cause problems

Comment: What does "it stops at the end of the three allpass" mean?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It means that i got to the output for the cascade allpass (as in the image 2). I need to add a loop for the lowpass filter

Comment: So you mean that the code itself does not stop running, but it only implements a part of the schematic you have shown?

Comment: I thought like an IIR Comb i need to append the output of the filter in the original input, but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: No, the code stops when the input file is filtered with the three allpass (so i have a result). I have to add the lowpass feedback.

Comment: @mkrieger1 If you want i can give you all my code, so you can try it yourself. I'm loosing my mind with this problem ahaha